# Gzip PHP exec dosent create a gz compressed file

Tags: php, gzip

I am using PHP exec

```
$copyBeforeDir = '/test/';
$fileProcessing = 'test.csv';
$zipStatus = exec("gzip ".$copyBeforeDir.$fileProcessing);
```

The paths are correct. The file exists. But there is no .gz file in that directory.  Running the same command in linux command line works though.

Edit:
This isnt a duplicate as I have ran exec on the same script and server for other jobs. I have fixed the problem and will post it in the solved answers.

Comment: full path ? permissions?

Comment: I have omitted the proper path but that is the equivalent.

Comment: have you tried with the full path of gzip ?

Comment: yeah, works in terminal but not via php

Comment: that's not the answer to my question